# How to display echo messages from a systemd-timer script in journalctl?

Tags: systemd, echo, systemd-journald, systemd-timer, journalctl

I run via a systemd timer a shell script that starts some programs (they display some output) and uses `echo` to provide some feedback.

```
root@srv ~ [127]# cat /etc/systemd/system/borg.timer
[Unit]
Description=runs borg every hour

[Timer]
OnCalendar=hourly
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
root@srv ~# cat /etc/systemd/system/borg.service
[Unit]
Description=borg backup

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/etc/local/borg.sh
```

```
root@srv ~# cat /etc/local/borg.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "→→→ starting borg backup at $(date)"

# it is OK to move repositories
export BORG_RELOCATED_REPO_ACCESS_IS_OK=yes
(...)
```

- When starting the script interactively I see both outputs (the program and `echo` ones) through `journalctl`.
- When running it via the timer only the program output is displayed.

I understand that the latter is a non-interactive run, but since the program output someone makes its way to `journalctl` so what not the timer?

Is there a way to make such feedback outputs from the script appear?

---

Below is a comparison of what is output via `systemctl` and `journalctl` when starting the script ad hoc via `sytemctl start borg`. I now wonder whether the fact that this is a "two-stage" script (`bash` running `borg.sh` which itself runs `python` behind the scenes) could be a reason for the filtered output (just a wild guess)

Output from `systemctl`:

```
root@srv ~# systemctl status borg
● borg.service - borg backup
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/borg.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-08-08 18:31:54 CEST; 1min 22s ago
TriggeredBy: ● borg.timer
   Main PID: 2651152 (borg.sh)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 28688)
     Memory: 1.1G
        CPU: 54.304s
     CGroup: /system.slice/borg.service
             ├─2651152 /bin/bash /etc/local/borg.sh
             └─2651737 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/borg compact /backup/borg/srv

Aug 08 18:32:46 srv borg.sh[2651687]: Keeping archive (rule: weekly #4):       231d5f07-3453-46a5-a466-b8760196e120 Sun, 2022-07-03 23:00:11 [ab22320beda4d0f4ac247686ad>
Aug 08 18:32:46 srv borg.sh[2651687]: Keeping archive (rule: monthly #1):      3b280578-586f-4f62-80c1-b296aa8982c2 Thu, 2022-06-30 23:00:10 [067e23be4b7e33ec7b87f32603>
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651687]: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651687]:                        Original size      Compressed size    Deduplicated size
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651687]: Deleted data:               -3.54 GB             -1.61 GB             -1.33 MB
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651687]: All archives:                2.23 TB              1.82 TB            104.85 GB
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651687]:                        Unique chunks         Total chunks
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651687]: Chunk index:                  199025              7333955
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651687]: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651152]: →→→ compact backup for /backup/borg/srv
Aug 08 18:33:28 srv borg.sh[2651152]: repo: /backup/borg/srv id: 2022-08-08T18:32:00+02:00 hash:
Aug 08 18:33:30 srv borg.sh[2651152]: →→→ ended backup on srv
Aug 08 18:33:30 srv borg.sh[2651152]: →→→ starting backup on outscale
Aug 08 18:33:30 srv borg.sh[2651152]: →→→ create backup for outscale@148.253.71.12:/backup/srv
Aug 08 18:33:32 srv borg.sh[2652145]: M /etc/docker/domotique/data/hass/.storage/hacs.repositories
Aug 08 18:33:32 srv borg.sh[2652145]: M /etc/docker/domotique/data/hass/.storage/auth
```

The same log lines via `journalctl`

```
Aug 08 18:32:46 srv borg.sh[2651687]: Keeping archive (rule: weekly #4):       231d5f07-3453-46a5-a466-b8760196e120 Sun, 2022-07-03 23:00:11 [ab22320beda4d0f4ac247686adb39bd64533d93c9b02172e4299bf5f7e8ceee8]
Aug 08 18:32:46 srv borg.sh[2651687]: Keeping archive (rule: monthly #1):      3b280578-586f-4f62-80c1-b296aa8982c2 Thu, 2022-06-30 23:00:10 [067e23be4b7e33ec7b87f32603d5a05aa5e1f77e6dff17451b3d63db9130cafc]
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651687]: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651687]:                        Original size      Compressed size    Deduplicated size
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651687]: Deleted data:               -3.54 GB             -1.61 GB             -1.33 MB
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651687]: All archives:                2.23 TB              1.82 TB            104.85 GB
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651687]:                        Unique chunks         Total chunks
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651687]: Chunk index:                  199025              7333955
Aug 08 18:32:48 srv borg.sh[2651687]: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 08 18:33:32 srv borg.sh[2652145]: M /etc/docker/domotique/data/hass/.storage/hacs.repositories
Aug 08 18:33:32 srv borg.sh[2652145]: M /etc/docker/domotique/data/hass/.storage/auth
```

Everything that starts with `→→→` (and the `repo` line I forgot to prefix) come from an `echo`.

Comment: the standard output from the shell script should get to journalctl just as well as standard output from whatever is run in `(...)` so I'm not sure why your echo output is not showing up. maybe try just a `date` or removing the fancy unicode characters?

Comment: @thrig I tried your suggestion, same result. It gave me the idea to update my question with a view of the same log lines from `systemctl` and `journalctl` perspectives.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to have the lines appear, but do not fully understand the difference:

```
root@srv ~ [SIGINT]# journalctl -u borg -f
Aug 08 18:34:59 srv borg.sh[2652992]: All archives:                1.10 TB            806.57 GB             23.34 GB
Aug 08 18:34:59 srv borg.sh[2652992]:                        Unique chunks         Total chunks
Aug 08 18:34:59 srv borg.sh[2652992]: Chunk index:                  104061              5351569
Aug 08 18:34:59 srv borg.sh[2652992]: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 08 18:34:59 srv borg.sh[2651152]: →→→ compact backup for outscale@148.253.71.12:/backup/srv
Aug 08 18:35:01 srv borg.sh[2651152]: repo: outscale@148.253.71.12:/backup/srv id: 2022-08-08T18:33:30+02:00 hash:
Aug 08 18:35:03 srv borg.sh[2651152]: →→→ ended backup on outscale
Aug 08 18:35:04 srv borg.sh[2651152]: →→→ ended borg backup at Mon Aug  8 18:35:04 CEST 2022
```

I was previously using

```
root@srv ~ [SIGINT]# journalctl _COMM=borg -f
Aug 08 18:34:58 srv borg.sh[2652992]: Keeping archive (rule: daily #3):        16cccd33-5293-4a5f-8d36-35a46bfbe3b4 Wed, 2022-08-03 23:00:47 [5ae28fbaef906725950b9b672935c5c1ff9ebc8987c1fb8d96b3db65bbd6e375]
Aug 08 18:34:58 srv borg.sh[2652992]: Keeping archive (rule: daily #4):        226cc3ae-255e-4e24-977b-db1fa32fa741 Tue, 2022-08-02 23:00:55 [271d41a84227ffa104d18073e83760e190b3ec8a255852f7f23e404b50ead583]
Aug 08 18:34:58 srv borg.sh[2652992]: Keeping archive (rule: daily[oldest] #5): 2f43aa48-f6b4-4f69-b4da-d32a3ae3bcf7 Tue, 2022-08-02 16:01:05 [e8c9e47e7dac4f502c1259fbdb19a5783b6b081203dff7d4809ef763467d4c96]
Aug 08 18:34:59 srv borg.sh[2652992]: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 08 18:34:59 srv borg.sh[2652992]:                        Original size      Compressed size    Deduplicated size
Aug 08 18:34:59 srv borg.sh[2652992]: Deleted data:                    0 B                  0 B                  0 B
Aug 08 18:34:59 srv borg.sh[2652992]: All archives:                1.10 TB            806.57 GB             23.34 GB
Aug 08 18:34:59 srv borg.sh[2652992]:                        Unique chunks         Total chunks
Aug 08 18:34:59 srv borg.sh[2652992]: Chunk index:                  104061              5351569
Aug 08 18:34:59 srv borg.sh[2652992]: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```